# Total records in sqlite table

Tags: sqlite

I am building a small web application with `Tomcat` and I use a `sqlite` DB system. Because I have very little experience in DB, I was wondering if there is any limitation, on how many records a table in sqlite can have?

Comment: Can you explain plz, why the negative vote??

Comment: `The theoretical maximum number of rows in a table is 2^64 (18446744073709551616 or about 1.8e+19). This limit is unreachable since the maximum database size of 140 terabytes will be reached first. A 140 terabytes database can hold no more than approximately 1e+13 rows, and then only if there are no indices and if each row contains very little data.` - https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html

Comment: Because minimal effort in research would answer your question. And why are the upvotes?

Comment: I searched it, but i didn't find anything. My google query 'Total records in sqlite table' didn't return me sth useful. Now I see, that i should have searched for `maximum` and not total

Comment: You can close your own post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Maximum length of a string or BLOB
>
> ```
> The maximum number of bytes in a string or BLOB in SQLite is defined by the preprocessor macro SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH. The default value
> ```
>
> of this macro is 1 billion (1 thousand million or 1,000,000,000). You
>   can raise or lower this value at compile-time using a command-line
>   option like this:
>
> ```
>  -DSQLITE_MAX_LENGTH=123456789
> ```
>
> The current implementation will only support a string or BLOB length up to 2<sup>31</sup>-1 or 2147483647. And some built-in
>
> functions such as hex() might fail well before that point. In
>   security-sensitive applications it is best not to try to increase the
>   maximum string and blob length. In fact, you might do well to lower
>   the maximum string and blob length to something more in the range of a
>   few million if that is possible.

for more infoormation

Maximum Number Of Rows In A Table

> The theoretical maximum number of rows in a table is 2<sup>64</sup>
>   (18446744073709551616 or about 1.8e+19). This limit is unreachable
>   since the maximum database size of 14 terabytes will be reached first.
>   A 14 terabytes database can hold no more than approximately 1e+13
>   rows, and then only if there are no indices and if each row contains
>   very little data.

https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html